# Switching attention - is there a statistical tool to mimic perceptive response?

Tags: forecasting, weighted-regression

I was driving this morning to work. Another car made sudden lane change. I noticed an interesting thing: for a brief moment my attention focused in this car. It almost physically felt that everything else sort of disappeared for a moment, and my eyes and brain and entire body were determined to figure out what's going with this object. Once, it merged with a flow, the focus dispersed and I went back to monitoring everything around me.

So, I thought about a statistical forecasting model that could have this property whereas it would notice something unusual, then focus on the feature evaluate it and undial once the feature disappeared. Maybe you have a bunch of predictors, then for some reason the weight is increased on one of them for some time, then get the weight back to equal. For instance, in the last crisis it could have been something related to real estate, maybe underwriting fraud indicators or deterioration of retail borrower's credit that had to be picked up my forecasting models. Most forecasters missed the last crisis because their weights are static in regression models, in my opinion.

Comment: Something vaguely like this in using control charts to monitor a process. Sound alarm according to any one of several criteria: too many observations on same side of $\mu,$ too many successive increases or decreases, any observation farther than $3\sigma$ from $\mu,$ and so on. Also, maybe several characteristics being monitored. Alarm may trigger temporary production stop, extensive evaluation, temporarily stricter rules for second alarm, and so on. (Very basic statistics, each point controversial, many variations of implementation.)

Comment: Basically it is a good idea. However, your dynamic weighs has to take into account that having all your attention focused does not mean everything else disappear. Otherwise all your automatic function (heart beat, breath,...) would have stop. Also you would have been unable to react to other dangers: a pedestrian or an animal may have cross your way, an other car may have changed line, or a ambulance car may have come behind claiming for priority.

Comment: @AlainD, we have some kind of a threat detection and reaction in our brains. I agree that it's not 100% focus on a threat, but it seems that it can get close to 100% when the threat level increases. I was just wandering if there were simple statistical approaches to emulate this for econ/finance forecasting. the cool thing about brains is that it can react rather well to unanticipated and new threats, which our model typically are not good with

Comment: I guess any model will do as long as you put more weight on the recent observations. For example, an exponential smoothing with a large smoothing factor. If you want to emulate the brain, you can try to train you model based on the last values (exponential smoothing) and the average.